# Dynamic Paint with object material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, dynamic-paint

How do I use dynamic paint (cycles) to paint with an object with texture. The dynamic paint / brush in BI seems to have a “use object material” setting to allow the brush to use the paint from a material, but cycles does not have this option. Is it possible to use an image texture to dynamic paint in cycles?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use an attribute node with the value of `dp_paintmap`(if you are using the default) and connect that to the factor input of a mix node.
[image]
  Your painted material will be on the bottom while the other material will be on the top.  Be sure that you hit the plus next to Paintmap under Dynamic Paint Output in the Physics tab.[image]