# How to make dynamic paint effect distinctly visible?

Tags: materials, dynamic-paint

I was trying to create a painting effect (a simple brush rolled over a surface changes the color of the surface to that of the brush) with dynamic paint. So, I added a canvas and a brush, kept the Dynamic Paint advanced surface type to Paint, and use the object's material to paint. But as you can see in the picture the paint effect is hardly visible, in fact its not even sure whether it's a small reflection from the shader or actually the paint effect. So, how do you make the paint effect distinct? Any suggestion is appreciated

[image].Thanks

Comment: Are you using the vertex colours (or image sequence) specified in the brush's 'Dynamic Paint Output' panel in your material? If you're not, you're generating the dynamic paint data, but not actually using it.

Comment: I m using vertex colours

Comment: Right, but are you implementing them in your material? Are you able to see the paint effect in solid view? You should be able to.

Comment: yeah man i can see them in solid view.The problem appears to be while rendering.It seems to be unrendered.

Comment: Can add a screenshot showing the material of the plane?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Paint not showing in rendered image](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/dynamic-paint-not-showing-in-rendered-image) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/dynamic-paint-with-object-material-in-cycles

Comment: OK thanks guys,both Ray and cegaton. That ought to do.