# Using a hand painted mask texture to hide part of the results of a shader node

Tags: shader-nodes, masking

So I want to have several node textures in one material partially masked in different ways and I was wondering if you could manually paint masks to hide certain parts of a shader node´s results to only show what you want, not sure how to go about this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/dynamic-paint-with-object-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/how-to-fade-one-material-into-the-other https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/cycles-gradient-between-two-materials/